# How do I make the new long position not close the previous short position so that the win rate of the strategy is calculated separately?

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to make each trading position close only with its exit() function,
not with the next reverse position,
What should I do?

```
.
.
.

id  = (dir == 1.0 ?"LONG":"SHORT")+str.tostring(getPartOfOrder("uniqID",orderID))
qty = math.abs((risk/100 * (compositEffect?strategy.equity:strategy.initial_capital) )/ (en - sl))//math.abs(risk/100* (compositEffect?strategy.equity:strategy.initial_capital)/(en-sl))
qty := checkMaxQty? ((qty<=maxQty)?qty:maxQty) : qty 
strategy.entry(id,buyOrSell,qty=qty,limit=en)
strategy.exit("close_"+id,id,qty_percent=100,limit=tp1,stop=sl)

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current position is flat before entry:

```
id  = (dir == 1.0 ?"LONG":"SHORT")+str.tostring(getPartOfOrder("uniqID",orderID))
qty = math.abs((risk/100 * (compositEffect?strategy.equity:strategy.initial_capital) )/ (en - sl))//math.abs(risk/100* (compositEffect?strategy.equity:strategy.initial_capital)/(en-sl))
qty := checkMaxQty? ((qty<=maxQty)?qty:maxQty) : qty 
if strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry(id,buyOrSell,qty=qty,limit=en)
strategy.exit("close_"+id,id,qty_percent=100,limit=tp1,stop=sl)
```